# Shortenend form for "The diameters given are the inside diameters"

Tags: terminology

This is the sentence to be written in a report - "The diameters given are the inner side diameters". But that seems wordy, especially because of the repetition of "diameters". I found a usage similar to this one in a scientific publication:

1. Given are the inner diameters.

How much correct is that? Or is it more appropriate to follow any of the below ones?

2. The diameters are for the inner sides
3. The diameters are of the inner sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tangent: In the US we normally say "inside diameter" and not "inner side diameter". I don't know if that's different in other English-speaking countries.

You could say, "Diameters given are of the inside" (or "of the inner side" if you prefer). This sounds a little awkward to me.

Personally I would probably just use another word in place of the first "diameter" to avoid the repetition. Like, "Sizes given are inside diameters."

Depending on context, you could say, "In this report we use inside diameters." That's not much shorter but it avoid the repetition.

If they're given in a chart, you could just label the column "Inside diameter".

You could also label them "ID", like "0.5 inches ID". That's a common abbreviation for "inside diameter". (As opposed to OD for outside diameter.)